# AYUDA HTML-PHP-FILE

Tags: php, html, archivo

Resumiendo: trabajo en una pagina en la que para participar en un sorteo tienen que dejar un nombre y una foto.
mi problema esta cuando hay que guardar las fotos. es muy selectivo con la clase de fotos que deja guardar, y no es por el tamaño, ni el tipo de imagen.
Dejo el formulario:

Este es el código **`PHP:`**

```php
<?php
include ("conexion.php");

if ($_FILES["imagen"]["size"]>10000000) {
    # code...
    echo "El archivo debe pesar menos de 4 MG";
    echo "<script> window.location='../turecuerdo.html'; </script>";
    exit();
}
$dir="img/";
$nombre_archivo = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
if (! move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'],$dir.$nombre_archivo)) {
    # code...
        echo "<script> alert('Error en la subida de archivos, Pruebe nuevamente')</script>";
    echo "<script> window.location='../turecuerdo.html'; </script>";
        exit();
}


$participante=$_POST['nombre'];
$delegacion=$_POST['delegacion'];
$Consulta = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO album (participante,delegacion,rutaa,nombreimg) VALUES ('$participante','$delegacion','$dir','$nombre_archivo')");
$Consulta->execute();
echo '<script> Alert("Registrado con exito")"; </script>';
echo '<script> window.location="../turecuerdo.html"; </script>';
?>
```

Y este es el **`HTML`** resumido:

```html
<form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="php/cargar.php" method="POST">
    Nombre:
    <input required type="text"   name="nombre" placeholder="Ej: Tomas Hernandez"><br>Delegación:
    <input required type="text"   name="delegacion" placeholder="Ej: Buenos Aires"><br>

    <input required type="file" target="_blank" class="custom-file-input" accept="image/*"  id="imagen" name="imagen">
    <label > foto </label>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Participar">
</form>
```

**REITERO, ALGUNAS FOTOS ME DEJA SUBIR, PERO OTRAS NO**

Comment: se mas claro y específico, cuales si te deja subir? formato, peso, etc; así como preguntas es muy amplio pues el único que sabe lo que esta ocurriendo eres tu

Comment: cualquier imagen imagen, hasta 10mb

Comment: Activa temporalmente el reporte de errores al inicio del script, guarda, intenta de nuevo y dinos qué error muestra: `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: Comprueba que a nivel de servidor, por ejemplo en tu php.ini, no tengas ninguna restricción de tipo max_file_uploads=10M. Si es así, lo podrías incrementar.